# Unable to get Current Date in MongoDB View Query

Tags: mongodb

We have meteor app and we’re using mongodb as database. Now, since the VIEW feature is already available on mongodb we tried to use it to generate a report. However, we are having issue on comparison to our collection date field and to the current date, we cannot even retrieved current date field using mongodb aggregate under $project because we don’t know the right syntax to get the current date. Our goal is since it’s using view we would like to replace new Date() (which is the today’s date in below codes) to the current date method of mongodb.

```
"waiting_for_appointment" : {
            $cond : {
                if: { $eq: ["$current_status", "Waiting For Appointment"]},
                then: {
                    $cond : {
                         if: {$gt: [{$subtract: [ new Date(), "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}, 0]},
                         then: {
                            $cond: {
                                if: {$gt: [{$subtract: [ "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.to_date", "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}, 0]},
                                then: {$multiply : [{
                                    $divide: [{$subtract: [ new Date(), "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}, {$subtract: [ "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.to_date", "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}]
                                    }, 100]
                                },
                                else: 0
                            }
                         },
                         else: 0
                    }
                },
                else: -1
            }
        },
```

The query works correctly but when I edit again the VIEW query I found that it is converted to static date, the date when was the query is saved. This is what we got after saving the query and editing it back.

```
ISODate("2017-10-09T02:12:42.282+0000")
```

That’s why, the query will not be effective if the date is changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @JuvyCagape, I've got the same issue - have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Starting with MongoDB 4.2, you can now use the variable $$NOW.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/

```
{
   current_date: '$$NOW'
}
```

If you want to use this in an aggregation within a view, you can combine it with $addFields also. For example:

```
[
 {
    $addFields: {
        current_date: '$$NOW'
    }
 }, 
 {
    $project: {
        differenceMilli: {
            $subtract: [
            '$current_date',
            '$updated_at'
        ]
    }
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, when you're setting Object Literals (which you're doing with this whole query in this case), all of the called functions in the object are called at the moment the object is instantiated.

*NOTE: I haven't poured through your complex query. I'm really just speaking to the issue of having an updated date and assuming that the query structure is sound.*

I don't know your use case, but if you can invoke this as a function instead of an object, you can pretty easily get updated parameters at the moment of invocation.

```
const someObj = {

    "waiting_for_appointment" : function( currentDate ) {
        $cond : {
            if: { $eq: ["$current_status", "Waiting For Appointment"]},
            then: {
                $cond : {
                     if: {$gt: [{$subtract: [ currentDate, "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}, 0]},
                     then: {
                        $cond: {
                            if: {$gt: [{$subtract: [ "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.to_date", "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}, 0]},
                            then: {$multiply : [{
                                $divide: [{$subtract: [ currentDate, "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}, {$subtract: [ "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.to_date", "$statuses.waiting_for_appointment.from_date" ]}]
                                }, 100]
                            },
                            else: 0
                        }
                     },
                     else: 0
                }
            },
            else: -1
        }
    },

}
```

And then `someObj['waiting_for_appointment'](new Date())` will return the query object with the current datetime.

Comment: Hi @Dom, thanks for the reply. Just want to clarify if you're doing that on VIEW feature of mongoDB? That view feature, we can store a mongodb statement i.e aggregate type or what ever and we can just call on our app i.e meteor app as a collection using find method. The goal is how can we store the actual date on mongodb view that will not transform into static. Like what I've explained above, we are using the `new Date()` in our statement but after you saved that statement it is converted to static as `ISODate("2017-10-09T02:12:42.282+0000")`.

Comment: Ah, right. You might have to drop and re-create the view in order to get your intended result, which might contradict the reason you wanted to use a view in the first place. I'll let you know if I find a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks @Dom, I'm still doing a research also on how. :-) Thanks for the help.